# How to move an Div to the bottom right side of an Image

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, aspect-ratio

So I have an Image card that I want to place an element to the bottom right of the image.

I'm using the TailwindCss aspect ratio plugin.
[image]

That Close X needs to be moved to the bottom-right side of the Image.

```html
<div class="mt-5 grid grid-cols-2 gap-3 px-3">
      <div class="aspect-w-3 aspect-h-4">
        <image
          src="http://unsplash.it/500/500?random&gravity=center"
          alt="Profile Image"
          class="rounded-md"
          layout="fill"
        />
        <div class="absolute bottom-2 right-0 text-white">X</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[This is a Codesandbox demonstrating the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-glade-6cdwos?file=/public/index.html:462-814)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the TailwindCss aspect ratio plugin uses padding and 0 height, position absolute will not work as intended. So we can use flex to our advantage.

```
<div class="mt-5 grid grid-cols-2 gap-3 px-3">
  <div class="flex aspect-w-3 aspect-h-4">
    <image
      src="http://unsplash.it/500/500?random&gravity=center"
      alt="Profile Image"
      class="rounded-md"
      layout="fill"
    />
    <div class="flex items-end justify-end p-5 text-white">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working Solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-morning-ggr841?file=/public/index.html

Answer (score 3):

you just need add `relative` class in div parent of image and add `w-full` class in image element,  because width of image will be fit with width of div parent.

```
    <div class="mt-5 grid grid-cols-2 gap-3 px-3">
       <div class="aspect-w-3 aspect-h-4 relative">
         <image
          src="http://unsplash.it/500/500?random&gravity=center"
          alt="Profile Image"
          class="rounded-md w-full"
          layout="fill"
         />
         <div class="absolute bottom-2 right-0 text-white">X</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `relative` class to the `div` with the aspect ration styles.

```
<div class="mt-5 grid grid-cols-2 gap-3 px-3">
  <div class="aspect-w-3 aspect-h-4 relative">
    <image src="https://unsplash.it/500/500?random&gravity=center" alt="Profile Image" class="rounded-md" layout="fill" />
    <div class="absolute bottom-2 right-0 text-white">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/7yFSnphcyq

**EDIT**

Updated answer that does not require the aspect ratio plugin and uses arbitrary values instead `aspect-[3/4]`. It also replaces the deprecated `<image>` tag which I would not recommend you use.

```
<div class="mt-5 grid grid-cols-2 gap-3 px-3">
  <div class="relative aspect-[3/4]">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/500?random&gravity=center" alt="Profile Image" class="rounded-md w-full h-full" />
    <div class="absolute bottom-2 right-0 text-white">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/TLAPFmRbZr

Comment: Your code doesn't import the https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-aspect-ratio. So the aspect ratio utility classes are not being applied. if You resize your image you would notice that it doesn't hold the aspect ratio.

Comment: For what its worth I have updated my answer. I think you were on the right track, and you  needed to change very little.